# WhatsApp url scheme for iPhone app

Tags: iphone, url-scheme

We are developing an iPhone app and planning to integrate Whatsapp.

Is there a way to enable click to call / message from the iPhone app? Skype allows this by following:

```
<a href="skype:skypehandle?call"> Skype </a>
```

Is there an equivalent for Whatsapp ?

Answer (score 10):

currently Whatsapp doesn't have a registered URL scheme.

You can check if you favourite apps support them by inspecting the contents of the apps info.plist.

I'm sure there are windows equivalents but I use a mac, so have a free app called iPhone Explorer (now renamed to iExplorer) installed which mounts the phone as a drive and allows you to view app contents via a tree structure.
No jailbreak required.
The info.plist is in the chosen apps appname.app folder. 
copy this to your desktop and open the file.
Look for the 'URL types' key and expand. This is the URL that when :// is added will open in safari or with the UIApplication openURL method.

**update - November 2012 -** latest version now adds URL scheme.
whatsapp://

don't know if it has any 'actions' associated with it though.

**update - Nov 2013**
Whatsapp blog has info on the actions that can be performed
http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/iphone/23559013

Answer (score 8):

```
NSURL *whatsappURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"whatsapp://location?id=1"];

 if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:whatsappURL]) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:whatsappURL]]];
 }
```

Comment: hello tell me ehn its works suessfully and what is location?id ??? .and how to use location id in iphone app .thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 8):

17/07/2013 Since yesterday's update, whatsapp has a public URL Scheme:

[Whatsapp official URL Scheme](http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/iphone/23559013)

Answer (score 5):

There are a few sites that list numerous iPhone app URL Schemes.  http://handleopenurl.com/scheme?page=27  is the largest one that I know of.  It doesn't seem to contain anything for WhatsApp.

http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes  is another list, but also doesn't include WhatsApp.
It's up to the developer of the app to create and publish their own URL Schemes, and it doesn't look like WhatsApp have done so yet.

Answer (score 3):

With the new iPhone v2.10.1 release WhatsApp now supports its own url scheme. E.g. to open a new chat composer with the text "Hello World" you have to do this:

```
NSURL *whatsappURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"whatsapp://send?text=Hello%20World!"];
 if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL: whatsappURL]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: whatsappURL];
 }
```

More information can be found in this FAQ on their site:
http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/iphone/23559013

Comment: There's also a WhatsAppKit on Github now: https://github.com/fawkeswei/WhatsAppKit

Comment: But how do you send abid(Addressbook ID)with that URL? THey did not show that.

Comment: try @"whatsapp://send?abid&text=hello%20World"   note abid is an integer (could be more) corresponding to the address book record id of a person.

Comment: I'm trying to open a person chat screen As Below
But its just opening whatsapp
The Code Is As Fallows

Comment: NSString *urlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"whatsapp://send?%dtext=SomeMessage",personAddressBookID];
        NSURL *whatsappURL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlStr];
        BOOL canOpenWhatsappUrl =  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:whatsappURL];
        if (canOpenWhatsappUrl == true)
        {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:whatsappURL];
        }
i'Ve tried
        NSString *urlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"whatsapp://send?%d",personAddressBookID];

Comment: This isn't working in iOS 9 beta. Has something been changed?