# whatsapp url scheme ios dev

Tags: ios, url, url-scheme, whatsapp

In the new version whatsapp implemented url scheme like

```
NSURL *whatsAppURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"Whatsapp://"];

if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:whatsAppURL]) {

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:whatsAppURL];

}
```

anyone knows if there is any action related to that? like create a new message?

Comment: Ouch, what are you doing with that poor URL? You have a proper `NSURL` object, why convert it to a string, then back to an `NSURL`?

Comment: @H2CO3 is right: `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: whatsAppURL]` is more than enough.

Comment: Have you looked at the Whatsapp website to see if they document their URL scheme? They would know better than anyone on SO.

Comment: @H2CO3, by the way he got the code from here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8959918/846273

Comment: @GabrielePetronella Thanks, good to know. Removed that black magic. I don't like to see others encouraging bad practice like this.

Comment: @H2CO3 did the same over here. After all the question meaning is still preserved.

Comment: @GabrielePetronella Thanks. Absolutely.

Comment: Thanks everyone, as @H2CO3 said i took the code from another post.

Answer (score 5):

With the new iPhone v2.10.1 release WhatsApp now publicly supports its own url scheme. E.g. to open a new chat composer with the text "Hello World" you have to do this:

```
NSURL *whatsappURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"whatsapp://send?text=Hello%20World!"];
 if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL: whatsappURL]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: whatsappURL];
 }
```

More information can be found in this FAQ on their site:
http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/iphone/23559013

Comment: There's also a WhatsAppKit on Github now: https://github.com/fawkeswei/WhatsAppKit

Comment: Is there any URL Scheme for WhatsApp to make call instead of message? Actually, i want to make call. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The `whatsapp://` URL scheme has been registered by WhatsApp, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10439662/846273), and you may be able to launch the WhatsApp application.

Unfortunately, at date, there's no documentation available so it's not known whether there are useful actions associated with it.

Comment: Thanks Gabriele, i searched into their website but can't find anything to developers.

Answer (score 3):

Three days ago, it became possible http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/iphone/23559013