# How do you find the url for an app that you would want to open in - app?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to open an app that would already be installed on a phone but need a url to open it. This is the function I'm using:

```
func openAppFromMenu(inAppURL: URL?, appStoreURL: URL?) {

    if inAppURL != nil {

        if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(inAppURL!)
        {
            UIApplication.shared.openURL(inAppURL!)
        } else {
            //redirect to safari because the user doesn't have in app
            print("App not installed")

            if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(appStoreURL! as URL) {
                UIApplication.shared.openURL(appStoreURL!)
            }
        }
    } else {
        //redirect to safari because the user doesn't in app
        print("App not installed")
        if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(appStoreURL! as URL) {
            UIApplication.shared.openURL(appStoreURL!)
        }
    }
}
```

How can I find the in-app and appstore url for the app?

Comment: Why are you using all of those crash operators (`!`)? Use `if let` and safely unwrap optionals.

Comment: I haven't refactored yet, right now I'm trying to find out how to get the proper URLs first

Comment: @SwiftyJD, for in-app url as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8958362/whatsapp-url-scheme-for-iphone-app), you can use iExplorer to go through info.plist of an app where you can look for 'URL types'